# How to control if json response return white page

Tags: python, json

I have a problem that, due to my little knowledge of python, I can't solve. I have this code, and when arrives at this command, the code stops working:

```py
req_ORDER_CURRENT = req_ORDER_CURRENT.json()
```

I noticed that if I launch the get on the browser, it returns me a blank page but response code is 200:

```
 req_ORDER_CURRENT = requests.get("http://" + ip + "/order/current")
 statusCodeReq     = req_ORDER_CURRENT.status_code
 print(req_ORDER_CURRENT)
 if statusCodeReq == 200:
    req_ORDER_CURRENT      = req_ORDER_CURRENT.json()
    print(req_ORDER_CURRENT.json())
```

Is there a system to control this situation?

Comment: Yes, you need to look at what is going on on the server side at that time.

Comment: @fukanchik I don't have the possibility because it is not a service developed by me

Comment: Does the website require login or access token?  Try to get one.

Comment: @fukanchik yes, but I can log in without any problem, if I make other calls they work perfectly, this get in certain situations unfortunately behaves in this way and I have to find a way to manage it without sending the script I am doing into error.